# Cosa significa "goliardico" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Questo fondo di religiosità mio padre lo mescolava a un forte senso del gioco e del cameratismo **goliardico**: intratteneva rapporti di confidenza, più che di fede, con alcuni santi, gli era soprattutto «simpatico» il sant'Antonio di un'ala laterale della chiesa di San Camillo. E, attribuendogli doti particolari di lealtà e di fluido amicale, faceva con lui periodici patti od accordi.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "goliardico" nel brano precedente. Ho letto tutte le [accezioni di questo aggettivo nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/goliardico/). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire quale sia il suo senso in questo contesto. Vuol dire che il padre di Gassman considerava i santi come se fossero i suoi colleghi di studio all'università? Significa che trattava i santi in modo privo di serietà o perfino un po' irreverente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La *goliardia* è una tradizione all'interno delle università italiane in cui gli studenti si vestono con abiti "medievali" e prendono parte ad attività irriverenti, bizzarre e spesso volgari. Ad esempio la [seguente canzone (NSFW)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijyOed8IvNAhVJVD4KHRiQCkUQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DySvykCIeX34&usg=AFQjCNHZNo16AWdbfoem-6cbH2Gj5yKLhA&sig2=sYgv6tqAiXmtM1Ga9w-0qQ) è una canzone goliardica e il [seguente radiodramma (NSFW)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY_ahAUkNZE) è una rappresentazione di uno storico brano teatrale goliardico.

In questo caso il brano indica che il padre di Gassman aveva un rapporto molto familiare con i santi, al punto da far battute volgari mentre pregava (o forse è meglio dire chiaccherava) con loro.

Answer (score -1):

Penso che si possa trattare di un semplice slittamento semantico, una ricercatezza espressiva che ha consentito allo scrittore di esprimere bene quanto aveva intenzione di dire. Finché si tratta di esigenze letterarie le variazioni semantiche sono interessanti e ci sono esempi illustri tra i poeti dell'ermetismo. Altra cosa è quando lo slittamento diventa deriva, smottamento, frana e di esempi ne possiamo fare tanti; ad esempio, l'uso del termine "clima" per "condizioni meteorologiche", errore commesso anche da giornalisti della TV i cui errori diventano linguaggio comune.
Per tornare alla domanda, alla quale non ho risposto, direi che la goliardia, l'esuberanza, l'entusiasmo di Gassman pervadeva ogni sua manifestazione vitale tra cui anche quella religiosa e quindi intratteneva rapporti "goliardici" anche con i santi. Non condivido questo atteggiamento religioso ma lo trovo simpatico e, comunque, innocuo; molto meglio di altre religiosità, che sono dannose, scure (altro slittamento), pervasive, costrittive, ecc.

Comment: Va bene ma, dalla tua spiegazione, continuo a non capire il significato di "goliardico" nel brano che ho citato.

Comment: Di tutto il discorso, solo le parole «la goliardia, l'esuberanza, l'entusiasmo di Gassman pervadeva ogni sua manifestazione vitale tra cui anche quella religiosa e quindi intratteneva rapporti "goliardici" anche con i santi» hanno qualche nesso con la domanda, ma di fatto non fanno che parafrasarla (visto che spiegare il senso di “goliardico” usando il termine “goliardia” non è di grande aiuto).